# WP REST API won't show data when not logged in

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

I want to fetch posts from my site, category wise and display them as a feed on a mobile app I am creating. The problem is, the data shows fine when I am logged in from WordPress but as soon as I log out, the data stream goes empty. The posts are public and there shouldn't be any need to authentication.

Has anyone encountered same issue?

Comment: If besides knowing if anyone faced the same issue you'd like to get some solution, I'd suggest you to edit your question adding the code you use to query the posts.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You need to authenticate, refer below links for create post with different types of Auth,

Cookie or Nonce based Auth refer below URLs,
http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/ https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

You can use below WP REST API create post method, Reference URL for create post : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I already have created posts, it is a live site. Is there a way to fetch the existing posts through REST API WordPress and display the data on mobile?

Comment: You can list of post or particular post by post id, REF: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts

Comment: If you communicate with WP REST in third party then need to implement AUTH. for only getting list of post you don't need auth. i think so.

Comment: For the testing just add below namespace in your website url and test " wp-json/wp/v2/posts ". If you hit this url in browser you can get json response of list of post. Note: WP version 4.7 or more OR not need to install wp rest plugin